# Google Play Music limit amount of space it can take on SD card

Tags: google-play-music

Google Play Music has the tendency to totally fill up my SD card with cache files for streaming. Now I do like this as 3g connection when travelling can be flaky and this way you minimise re-streaming of music you have recently been listening too (so unchecking this option in the settings is not a solution).

Problem arise that Google Play Music is taking up all available space which leads to other applications (Evernote in this case particularly) to complain about having not enough space on the SD card (total free space at the moment is 95mb but this still leads to Evernote shouting warnings/errors).

Is there a way to limit an app like this for the total space it can take on the SD card?

Comment: I've the same problem, so I suppose it is still not fixed. Am I right or is there any way to set the limit?

Comment: Nop, haven't found away so-far to get this sorted/fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to limit the size of the cache for the google music app. People have been asking for it since it came out though, so hopefully it appears in a future update.

Comment: Ok, pity! I was hoping for maybe even a more global android wide solution.... It anyway looks like development for Google Music app is extremely slow :(

Comment: I'm actually surprised by the lack of development for Google Music. It's a great service that is a big plus for the Android ecosystem and really fits in with Google's everything in the cloud mantra so I thought they'd be really focusing on it. Hopefully, there are some improvements with JellyBean.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative until Google gets their act together is to use an cache clearing app like Clean Master (I have no affiliation with it). You can set up an app like this so that it will automatically remind you to clear your cache, whether it be by date frequency or by size.